# WPF Text rendering problem

Tags: wpf, text, rendering

I created a custom control similar to TabControl. It works nice, except that the text in header items gets blury when I resize the content. It can, for example look like this:

[image]

Not only the text, but the box around the text can also get non-vertical. See the blue border around the "General" item:

[image]

What is causing this problem? I have set SnapToDevicePixels = True.
Thanks for any ideas!

**EDIT**:

I'm using .NET 4.0. TextOptions.TextFormattingMode is set to "Display".

The whole problem with fuzzy text and background occurs if I apply a DropShadowEffect effect in the style for ItemsControl which displays the buttons. This is the code for the Effect:

```
<Setter Property="Effect">
    <Setter.Value>
        <DropShadowEffect Direction="0" ShadowDepth="1" BlurRadius="10" Opacity="0.2" Color="Black" />
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

If this code is not enabled, the the text and the borders get displayed nicely.

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem here. It only occurs when using a DropShadowEffect and TextFormattingMode=Display. Removing one of them fixes the problem, but either it does not have a shadow or the text looks blurred like before .NET 4. This is really annoying. Please let us know if you found a solution!

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: no I haven't. And the thing is that this anomaly only occurs on some computers and not everywhere.

Comment: I have it on one project without problem and on the other text is very blurry. Same computer, same VS, same .net so it not computer specific

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you've said it yourself: `SnapToDevicePixels` will ruin text rendering if you've resized the text so it displays across pixels.  You probably want to keep `SnapToDevicePixels="True"` on your borders/backgrounds, but turn it off for the text elements.

As for your border... can you post the xaml?  I'm guessing that you're not using just a single element with rounded corners - are you drawing the edge of that tab as three separate lines?

Comment: I changed SnapToDevicePixels to false and still get the same result. The xaml for everything is quite large so I don't think it would make sense to publish it. The blue buttons are of type ToggleButton and the content of the button has several borders:

Comment: <Grid ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
<Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="2,2,0,0" Opacity="0" Background="{x:Null}" />
<Border Margin="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="2,2,0,0" Opacity="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" />
<Border BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="2" Visibility="Visible" Opacity="0" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" />
<Border Margin="1,1,1,0" Opacity="0" CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" />
<Border Opacity="0" BorderBrush="#FFB6BABF" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="2,2,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,0">

Comment: as I noted in my edited question, the whole problem only occurs if I set Effect property to a DropShadowEffect. Without that effect, there are no problems with rendering.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things to consider:

- are you using .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.0? reason why I'm asking is that the text rendering has been changed between the versions. In 4.0 it's a lot better.
- Sometime you have to wait a little while until the text get's sharper, so you scroll around, and then after a second the text becomes sharper. That could be as well a reason for you're issue.

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.0. TextOptions.TextFormattingMode is set to "Display"

Comment: and waiting for text to become sharper is not the issue here. It stays the same, no matter how long I wait.